# Multiple Jenkins pointing to single Sonar

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Currently we are having multiple Jenkins instances which are hosted on different boxes. 
Can we configure all of them to use the same sonar instance for analysis?

Answer (score 2):

Why Not ?
The Jenkins SonarQube plugin is just a javaRunner process that connect to Sonar, gather required libraries and execute SonarExecutor plugins ...

There is not specific restritions against this behavior.